# Extracting part of URL using java regular expression

Tags: java, regex, expression

I'm trying to extract part of the URL in the text files.

for example:

```
/p/gnomecatalog/bugs/search/?q=status%3Aclosed-accepted+or+status%3Awont-fix+or+status%3Aclosed" class="search_bin"><span>Closed Tickets</span></a>
```

I would like to extract only

```
 /p/gnomecatalog/bugs/search/?q=status%3Aclosed-accepted+or+status%3Awont-fix+or+status%3Aclosed
```

HOW I COULD DO THAT BY USING REGULAR Expression. I tried with regex

```
  "/p/*./bugs/*."
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: This looks like HTML. If you are doing this for fun then whatever, but if you want some sort of stability, then I suggest that you use a HTML parser. Jsoup is one such library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   "\/p.*\/bugs[^"]*"
```

it means: "/p"

then: all chars,

then: "/bugs",

then: all chars except `"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
(\/p\/.*\/bugs\/.*?(?="))
```

**Java Code :**

```
        String REGEX = "(\\/p\\/.*\\/bugs\\/.*?(?=\"))";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        while (m.find()) {
                String matched = m.group();
                System.out.println("Mached :  "+ matched);

            }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Mached :  /p/gnomecatalog/bugs/search/?q=status%3Aclosed-accepted+or+status%3Awont-fix+or+status%3Aclosed
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mW7nB3)**

**Explanation:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
(?i)/p/[a-z/]+bugs/[^ "]+
```

The (?i) in the beginning makes the regex case insensitive so you don't have to worry about that. Then after bugs/ it will continue until it reaches either a space or a ".